# Why does Banana is printing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today I was trying random letters printing using nodejs, Somehow I tried to print 'banana' in log but unfortunately I miss `n` (letter) to log but still it works fine. Why does it prints whole `banana` instead of 'baaa'?

```js
('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a').toLowerCase();
```

The output is `banana` but why? Even if `+ +` (empty char) generates `NaN` then still it should print `bananaa` not just `banana`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: it tries to add as a number and gets a NaN and add's the rest as string and also NaN.toString is NaN so it becomes `baNaNa` without toLowerCase. Also doesnt matter when u do `'b' + 'a' + + 'c' + 'a'` this or any other character on the second letter, after + + sign

Comment: If you don't use `toLowercase()` you can see `NaN` in there which tells you that the math operation you're using (`+ + 'a'`) is resulting in something that isn't a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra `+` acts as a unary operator on the following 'a', and tries to coerce it to a number, resulting in NaN. The remaining `+` symbols are all interpreted as string concatenation which causes `NaN` to be coerced to string ie. `('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a') = ('b' + 'a' + NaN + 'a') = ('baNaNa')`.

Comment: You mean it also takes second `a` with `NaN`? Because it has 3 `a` without `NaN`

Comment: The middle 'a' is coerced to NaN by the preceding `+`, then the rest are concatenated as normal. If you evaluate `+ 'a'` in the dev console, you'll see it evaluates to NaN.

Comment: I got it, I just put it for fun & you got infinite amount of upvote :)  Have a nice day. Please modify the answer, maybe it will help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting !!

```
console.log(('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a').toLowerCase());

console.log(('b' + 'a' + + 'a' + 'a'));

console.log(( 'a' + + 'b' ));

//output
banana
baNaNa
aNaN
```

In the 3rd statement, the 'b' is not printed as   `+ + 'b' = NaN //not a number` and
`.toLowerCase()` makes it `nan` hence the word `banana`

Comment: Thanks brother, Now everybody understood the solution :) I already accept an ans. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding nothing with nothing, which is most likely returning NaN